# Am I overorganizing or underorganizing C++ code?

Tags: c++, code-organization

So I'm making my first serious project.

Namespace structure:

- Egg

  - Math
  - Physics
  - ...
  - Simulation

A header:

```
#ifndef EGG_PHYSICS_WORLD_HPP
#define EGG_PHYSICS_WORLD_HPP

namespace Egg {
namespace Physics {

class Body
{
public:
   Body();

   const Math::Vector2& GetPosition() const;

   /* ... */
};

} // namespace Physics
} // namespace Body

#endif // EGG_PHYSICS_WORLD_HPP
```

Questions:

- Is it a sane organization overall?
- Is it a good practice to create nested namespaces?
- Is it OK to use a name that's not fully specified (eg. `Math::Vector2`) name instead of `::Egg::Math::Vector2` in `::Egg::Physics` namespace?
- If nested namespaces are overorganizing, is it OK to use a single namespace but still use a folder structure, eg. Egg::World located in "Egg/Physics/World.hpp"?

Comment: Personally, I think you should ogranize less. There is far too much ogranization in the world. It might help to understand what [ogran](https://www.google.com/search?q=ogran) is, first, though! Or maybe even [OGRA](https://www.google.com/search?q=OGRA)?

Comment: What would you want to achieve with namespace organizazion? Hard to answer without a requirements background.

Comment: For your second question: is it a good practice to create nested namespace. My two cents: Yes.

Comment: I'm confused. Is this question about [gay rodeos](http://www.ogra.net/) or not?

Comment: @ErikE: *Oklahoma Gay Rodeo Association*? I am not sure how that relates to the question! (You should give a better link than that google search...)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz please see the [original, unedited version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15122493/revisions).

Comment: Yeah I went down the search results, saw the gay cowboys website and kept going. Results didn't get any more relevant.

Comment: @ErikE And you should see the original version of your comment.

Comment: @ta.speot.is "ogranization". The OP asked about ogranization. I tried to "answer". :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why and how should I use namespaces in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are overorganizing. If it is application code, I would not use namespace at all, normally. If you move code to reusable library, wrap it to namespace then, but not before. Use class names which make sense without namespace.

Comment: Totally agree. IMHO, namespaces are to avoid clashes between modules, not to organize the project. For organization just use meaningful names.

Comment: Is it OK to use a single namespace but still use a folder structure? Eg. Egg::World located in <Egg/Physics/World.hpp>? I'm afraid of stuff turning into a big homogeneous mess...

Comment: A bit of Java-ish background, it seems... uh?

Comment: @rodrigo Or he may just not like having 500 not really coherent files in one directory? Organizing code into folders isn't unheard of for C/C++ projects either, just imagine the linux kernel all in one large directory.

Comment: @lamefun Just organize your project forgetting namespaces exist. Have modules with clear dependency hierarchy, with separate source code directories (maybe subprojects depending on build system). Only then think if you should put some modules to some number of namespaces.

Comment: @Voo: Don't get me wrong... separating the sources in directories is perfectly fine. In big programs, even using namespaces sparingly can be beneficial. But you have to admit that the tendency of the OP to _pakageize_ looks a bit like Java.