# How can I push a Fibonacci number into external array?

Tags: c++, object, namespaces

I didn't know that declaring value on namespace is same as declaring value on global.

So I want to change my code which don't use global variable.

How can I keep track of Fibonacci number from 0 ~ 20 without using global variable?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Fibonacci(int num);
namespace Fib{
    int arr[100];
    int num;
}
int main(){
    cin >> Fib::num;
    Fibonacci(Fib::num);
    return 0;
}

int Fibonacci(int n){
    if(Fib::num < 1) return -1;
    int result = 0;
    int idx;
    result = (n == 0) ? 0 : (n == 1) ? 1 : Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2);
    Fib::arr[n] = result;
    if(n == Fib::num){
        for(idx=1; idx < n+1 ; idx++){
            cout << Fib::arr[idx] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should really read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c)

Comment: You should really read one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Isn't this the reason why you use classes?

Comment: @dandavis Oh, sorry , since my English writing skill is too bad, I wrote such a naive expression. sorry..

Comment: @PrateekGupta It depends. A class with only public static variables and functions are acting just like a namespace. If the OP doesn't need object instances, but want to group variables then namespaces might be a good solution.

Comment: The short answer is that yes, you're okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is not with usage of namespaces. It is with usage of global variables. There are unlimited reasons to **not** use global variables, and may be one or two scenarios where it is appropriate. It is **not** appropriate here.

Comment: Does using namespace means using global variables?

Comment: @nujabes, only if you put variables inside your namespace :)

Comment: Oh, then namespace obj1 { int a = 5 }

Comment: and namespace obj2 { int b = 5; } These statement uses global variables then?

Comment: You mean that I can't use namespace as 'object in Javascript'?

Comment: @nujabes, yes, your examples use global variables. It is usually not appropriate. Namespaces are not objects, by the way. Objects are, ... well, objects.

Comment: Then, how can I make a 'packages' which doesn't use global variables?

Comment: Thank you for kind answer :)

Comment: @nujabes, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, and what do you need those 'packages' for.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Fibonacci(int num);
namespace Fib{
    int arr[100];
    int num;
}
int main(){
    cin >> Fib::num;
    Fibonacci(Fib::num);
    return 0;
}

int Fibonacci(int n){
    if(Fib::num < 1) return -1;
    int result = 0;
    int idx;
    result = (n == 0) ? 0 : (n == 1) ? 1 : Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2);
    Fib::arr[n] = result;
    if(n == Fib::num){
        for(idx=1; idx < n+1 ; idx++){
            cout << Fib::arr[idx] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return result;
}

Comment: I want to push Fibonacci[0] ~ Fibonacci[20] value to the array, and I want to print of it. I thought that then I must use outer 'packages'.

Comment: @nujabes, edit the question with relevant code, or, since this question is in kinda bad shape, better create a new one.

Comment: Thank you Sergey!